# Real location of installed module python

Tags: python

I installed social.py

social.py code:

```
import os
social_dir = os.getdir()
arr = os.listdir()
```

I execute python in this directory: `/home/facts/Documents/FactsDigital/`

```
import sys
from social import social_dir, arr
print(social_dir)
print(arr)
>>> /home/facts/Documents/FactsDigital/
>>> "files python running cmd location"
```

How can I get the arr of real directory and not where I'm execute my code?

Comment: Modules include a `__file__` variable holding their file system name. You can `import social;print(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(social.__file__)))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to operate in `social.py` with the path not in the python running console... @tdelaney

Comment: `sudo find / -name "social.py"` is shell functions are allowed here

Comment: I just edited the question to be more clear @tdelaney

Answer (score 0):

1) To get the realpath of file being executed.

import os

print(os.path.realpath(__file__))

2) To get the directory of file being executed.

import os

print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))